# Question about strange IIS log activity?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, serverfault

I'm a developer trying to trace through a bug, and I'm seeing some very strange hits to my website.  I want to put up a question about it, does it belong on stackoverflow or serverfault?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest posting it on SF, and if the community there doesn't feel it's for them, they can always migrate it to a more appropriate site.

Comment: let's see what they say: http://serverfault.com/questions/138240/strange-iis-hits-originating-from-trend-micro :)